# different instances of an object having static data members- possible?

Tags: c++

I'd like to have 2 different `Data` instances used in the client without either changing the `static` key in its member or resetting its member's value.

```
struct Data
{
    static std::vector<int> vi;
};
struct DataUser
{
    DataUser(int s) {
        for (int i = 0; i < s; ++i)
        {
            Data::vi.emplace_back(i);
        }
    }
    int getSize() { return Data::vi.size(); }
};

std::vector<int> Data::vi(0);

//.............. use it
int main()
{
    {
       DataUser d1(5);
       std::cout << d1.getSize() << "\n";
    }
    {
        DataUser d2(10);
        std::cout << d2.getSize() << "\n";
    }
}
```

e.g the output of the program is

```
5
15
```

I'd like it to be

```
5
10
```

Comment: If each instance is to have its own copy, then it shouldn't be static to *any* class.

Comment: But what if I have to use it asa data member in templates ?

Comment: From your description it sounds like you just want to store an object of type `Data` in `DataUser`, not use `static`

Comment: It's somewhat unclear what behavior you are looking for. Why is `vi` static (or in a separate class...) in the first place if what you apparently *want* is each `DataUser` having its own `vi`?

Comment: @OstrichGroomer - What about it? I suggest you post a single concise [mcve] so we may avoid this guessing game where other requirements pop up.

Comment: @DevSolar I have more than 20 `Data`'s like that.

Comment: @OstrichGroomer: It's hard to answer an incomplete question. And this question is incomplete as the obvious answer -- *don't make it `static`* -- doesn't work for you. Please state your restrictions and requirements succinctly *in the question itself*. ("I have 20 of those" doesn't do it, either.) As it stands, it's "unclear what you're asking", and that's a close reason.

Answer (score 1):

`static` always means there is only one single instance of it in one binary.
The only way to have separate instances is to have a Data member and non static member in Data.